# How to login using the Mobile Number in Django Rest Framework.

Tags: python, django, rest

We are using the django rest framework, for the login module, with the phone number.

To authenticate the same, I want to use the OTP(One Time Password).
How this can be achieved.

This can be done using the auth-token of rest framework.
But that it doesn't seem to be a good idea.

Any other approach.
Please help.

Comment: Are you using Token Based Authentication ?

Comment: Yes. I am using the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For mobile and otp to work with your project, you will need to create your [own custom `User` model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model) with `mobile` as `username` and `otp` as `password` field.

After creating your own `User` model, you can then [create a new Token](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication), after creating a `User` instance using the mobile and otp.

You can create two simple views where you first generate the otp after the user enters a valid mobile number and another view to verify the otp, sending `token` in the response.

[An example on how to create a custom User model](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html#abstractbaseuser)

**Example**:

```
# views

@api_view(['POST'])
def generate_otp(request):
    mobile = request.data.get('mobile', None)
    if mobile:
         otp = random.randrange(lower_limit, upper_limit+1)
         User.objects.create(mobile=mobile, otp=otp)
         return Response({'success': True})
    else:
         ...

@api_view(['POST'])
def verify_otp(request):
    mobile = ...
    otp = request.data.get('otp', None)
    if mobile and otp:
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(mobile=mobile, otp=otp)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return Response({'message': 'Invalid OTP'})

        token = Token.objects.create(user=user)
        return Response({'token': token})
     else:
        ...
```

This is based on `rest_framework authtoken`, you can also use [JWT](https://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/), if you want to.

Comment: any idea how to implement jwt using only phone login and not password

Comment: @user190549 Post a new question clearly stating where you need help.